# Concatenating a formula with a variable inside

Tags: excel, vba

I want to concatenate a variable in side a formula, but I cannot get it to work:

```
For char_index = 1 To 48

    Cells(char_index, 2).Formula = "=MID('mysheet'!$B$8;" & CStr(char_index) & ";1)"

Next char_index
```

The idea is that the formula is added to column B from row 1 to 48 (or B1:B48).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cells(char_index, 2).Formula = "=MID('mysheet'!$B$8," & CStr(char_index) & ",1)"
```

Even if for your localization the list/formula separator is ";", in VBA you have to use "," and it will write the formula in the appropriate way...